# I can't see the Tailwindcss classes I wrote

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I wanted to make a simple todo list application, but I wrote the functions and everything is fine, but my Tailwindcss codes that I wrote do not work, what could be the reason?

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**The file structure is as follows:**

[image]

Comment: what is the contents of global.css?

Comment: I think you forgot the step `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` from here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: @LarsVonk Since there is next js in the project, I installed it according to the installation of next js, they were not there. Do I need to do these too?

Comment: @lanAndwati In the next js setup part, he told me to put them in global.css. The content is as follows: 
`@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;`

Comment: @LarsVonk this is a next js project. tailwind in integrated in the build process.

Comment: @miguner I thought maybe you had not included these directives.  In the docs the file is named `globals.css` not `global.css` , perhaps try changing that. If it doesn't work, then post the jsx files with the class names

Comment: did you use the `@tailwind base` in your `css` fiels

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

On your global.css and later, reset the server